# NGINX Container Routing: Nginx does not redirect to docker containers

Tags: nginx, server, docker-compose

I am new in web-servers. I am setting up a server (example.de) serving two different dockerized applications. The exposed ports 3000 (app1) and 5000 (app2) are mapped in server ports 9000 and 9001 respectively. Requesting the urls example.de:9000 and example.de:9001, the content is properly load. Now, I want to use a NGINX container as reverse proxy to redirect the urls example.de/app1, and example.de/app2.

"include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;" is set by default in the nginx.conf file.

The default.conf is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.de;


    location /app1{
      proxy_pass http://app1:3000; 
    }

    location /app2{
      proxy_pass http://app2:5000;
    }
}
```

The working docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app1:
        build:
            context: app1
        container_name: app1
        restart: "<RESTART_POLICY>"
        volumes:
            - vol_app1:/data
    app2:
        build:
            context: app2
        container_name: app2
        restart: "<RESTART_POLICY>"
        volumes:
            - vol_app2:/data
    nginx-proxy:
      container_name: nginx
      build:
        context: nginx/
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      depends_on:
        - app1
        - app2
      links:
        - app1
        - app2
      volumes:
        - vol_nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
volumes:
    vol_app1:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /vol/app1
            o: bind
    vol_app2:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /vol/app2
            o: bind
    vol_nginx:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /vol/nginx
            o: bind
```

The NGINX Dockerfile is:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

f the redirection is set like the default.conf, when I access the url http://example.de/app1, the browser request for */app1* not for the entrypoint */* (xxx.x.xx.xx - - [09/Aug/2019:06:31:57 +0000] "GET ***/app1*** HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-").

**UPDATE**

All containers are in the same network.
[Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):
`By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.`

**UPDATE II**

If I do not redirect, it works by adding upstream blocks to the default.conf:

```
upstream app1{
server app1:3000;
}

upstream app2{
server app2:5000;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.de;


    location / {
      proxy_pass http://app1; 
    }

}
```

Nevertheless, the path with /app1 and /app2 does not  redirect to the docker container.

Comment: were you able to fix the issue ?  If yes, how ?  I am also facing a similar issue...